# Drupal Views: Add Views signature to all SQL queries adding view name to Inner Join

Tags: views

When I preview my view, I get an error and notice that the view signature in the query was added twice. The one that's an issue is:

```
':default' AS view_name
```

Here is the full query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT taxonomy_term_data.tid AS tid, taxonomy_term_data.name AS taxonomy_term_data_name, taxonomy_term_data.vid AS taxonomy_term_data_vid, taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name AS taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name, 'video_categories:block' AS view_name
FROM {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data
INNER JOIN {node} node_taxonomy_term_data ON (SELECT nodeINNER.nid AS nidINNER, ':default' AS view_name
FROM {node} nodeINNER
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_indexINNER ON nodeINNER.nid = taxonomy_indexINNER.nid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data_nodeINNER ON taxonomy_indexINNER.tid = taxonomy_term_data_nodeINNER.tid
WHERE (( (taxonomy_term_data_nodeINNER.tid = taxonomy_term_data.tid ) ))
ORDER BY nodeINNER.nid DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) = node_taxonomy_term_data.nid
LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} taxonomy_vocabulary ON taxonomy_term_data.vid = taxonomy_vocabulary.vid
WHERE (( (taxonomy_vocabulary.machine_name IN  ('video_category')) ))
```

The error I get is:

```
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 2 column(s)
```

Which makes sense since I am not expecting the second parameter to be in there for view_name. Why does it do this and how do I stop this feature from adding the view_name to the inner join on my query?

When I uncheck this box, the query works as expected, however, I use the signature in my reporting to quickly identify issues, slow queries etc.

Comment: How are you doing the sub query with Views?5

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but the change to the view is adding "Taxonomy term: Representative node" as a relatinoship based on the Nid.

Comment: OK, I just don't recall ever seeing Views make a sub-SELECT (the `ON` clause starting on the third line of the query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the relationship added to the view. I removed the relationship and this fixed my issue.